# javax.json.JsonPatch unsupported as @RequestBody in Spring Webflux Microservice

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, json-patch

I'm currently messing around with a Spring Webflux microservice and trying to implement an @PatchMapping which consumes an JsonPatch object as @RequestBody like so:

```
@PatchMapping("/{id}", consumes = ["application/json-patch+json"])
fun updateFriend( @PathVariable("id") id: Long, 
                  @Valid @RequestBody jsonPatch: JsonPatch): Mono<UserFriends> {
    // apply JsonPatch code here...
}
```

I tested the endpoint with a Postman request like so:

```
PATCH <microservice-uri>/friends/1
Content-Type = application/json-patch+json
RequestBody = 
[
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "friends/11/since",
        "value": "<sample value>"
    }
]
```

And this is the exception I'm getting:

```
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class javax.json.JsonPatch]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `javax.json.JsonPatch` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.processException(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:211) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP PATCH "/friends/1" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
<Additional stacktraces here ...>
```

I am well aware of the fact, that I need to tell my microservice how to convert the RequestBody to a JsonPatch. But after failing for 3 days I decided to get some help.

After many unsuccessful tries I found the `WebFluxConfigurer` and tried overriding `configureArgumentResolvers`. I got stuck when writing the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` for JsonPatch.

```
class JsonPatchResolver : HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    override fun supportsParameter(parameter: MethodParameter): Boolean {
        // Don't know what to implement here
    }

    override fun resolveArgument(parameter: MethodParameter, bindingContext: BindingContext, exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<Any> {
        // Don't know how to create a JsonPatch from the given arguments
    }
}
```

Can somebody please point me in the right direction or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance!

**EDIT**
Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>friend-info-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>friend-info-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.72</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.java-json-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-patch</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr353</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**EDIT 2**
The following doesn't work:

```
class JsonPatchArgumentResolver : HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    override fun supportsParameter(parameter: MethodParameter): Boolean {
        // this doesn't event get called when debugging, so I suspect the handler isn't registered correctly
        return parameter.parameterType == JsonPatch::class
    }

    override fun resolveArgument(parameter: MethodParameter, bindingContext: BindingContext, exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<Any> {
        return exchange.request.body.toMono().map {
            jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(it.asInputStream(), JsonPatch::class.java)
        }
    }

}
```

And in my application class I'm registering it (maybe wrong, I dont know):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
@EnableWebFlux
@Configuration
class FriendInfoServiceApplication : WebFluxConfigurer {
    override fun configureArgumentResolvers(configurer: ArgumentResolverConfigurer) {
        configurer.addCustomResolver(JsonPatchArgumentResolver())
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<FriendInfoServiceApplication>(*args)
}
```

**EDIT 3**
While debugging I doscovered that the `configureArgumentResolvers` get's called, so maybe I'm doing something wrong with `supportsParameter`?

**EDIT 4**
I tried copying the code from [THIS](https://hugo-ma-alves.github.io/2020-02-01-json-patch-spring-application/) blog post. The kotlin equivalent should be:

```
@Component
class JsonPatchHttpMessageConverter : AbstractHttpMessageConverter<JsonPatch>() {

    @Throws(HttpMessageNotReadableException::class)
    protected override fun readInternal(clazz: Class<out JsonPatch>, inputMessage: HttpInputMessage): JsonPatch {
        try {
            Json.createReader(inputMessage.body).use { reader -> return Json.createPatch(reader.readArray()) }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw HttpMessageNotReadableException(e.message!!, inputMessage)
        }
    }

    @Throws(HttpMessageNotWritableException::class)
    protected override fun writeInternal(jsonPatch: JsonPatch, outputMessage: HttpOutputMessage) {
        throw NotImplementedError("The write Json patch is not implemented")
    }


    protected override fun supports(clazz: Class<*>): Boolean {
        return JsonPatch::class.java.isAssignableFrom(clazz)
    }
}
```

And added the objectMapper to the Application class like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
@EnableWebFlux
@Configuration
class FriendInfoServiceApplication {
    @Bean
    fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
        val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        objectMapper.registerModule(JSR353Module())
        return objectMapper
    }
}
```

The result sadly is the same exception when trying to call the PATCH endpoint.

Comment: I suspect you're using the wrong module - Are you definitely using the *Kotlin* Jackson module rather than the standard Java one? https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin

Comment: i can only point you in some type of direction, by looking into the source code you can see how the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` is implemented for, for example the `@RequestBody` annotation https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/RequestBodyMethodArgumentResolver.java

Comment: Thank you for the comments!
MichaelBerry I'm using the kotlin version of the jackson module, see my last edit with the pom.xml
ThomasAndolf This might get me somewhere. I tried implementing the HandlerMethodArgumentResolver interface, because I didn't knew there were abstract classes with more methods to use already inheriting from the interface. I'll try using them and keep you posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of the blog post you mentioned. I'm no expert in Webflux but in this case you'll have to re-implement the JacksonConverter to the webFlux form.

So it becomes something like this:

```
import org.springframework.core.ResolvableType
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.http.ReactiveHttpInputMessage
import org.springframework.http.codec.HttpMessageReader
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono
import javax.json.Json
import javax.json.JsonPatch

class JsonPatchHttpMessageConverter : HttpMessageReader<JsonPatch> {
    override fun getReadableMediaTypes(): List<MediaType> {
        return listOf(MediaType.valueOf("application/json-patch+json"))
    }

    override fun canRead(elementType: ResolvableType, mediaType: MediaType?): Boolean {
        return MediaType.valueOf("application/json-patch+json").includes(mediaType)
    }

    override fun read(elementType: ResolvableType, message: ReactiveHttpInputMessage, hints: Map<String, Any>): Flux<JsonPatch> {
        //TODO implement the same mono logic here
        return Flux.empty();
    }

    override fun readMono(elementType: ResolvableType, message: ReactiveHttpInputMessage, hints: Map<String, Any>): Mono<JsonPatch> {
        return DataBufferUtils.join(message.body).map { buffer: DataBuffer ->
            //TODO error handling
            val reader = Json.createReader(buffer.asInputStream())
            Json.createPatch(reader.readArray())
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it isn't fully implemented, you'll have to do the error handling and implement the `read(elementType: ResolvableType, message: ReactiveHttpInputMessage, hints: Map<String, Any>): Flux<JsonPatch>` .

Now you have to register this custom decoder. In spring webFlux you can do it by creating an WebFluxConfigurer bean:

```
@Bean
fun webFluxConfigurer(): WebFluxConfigurer {
    return object : WebFluxConfigurer {
        override fun configureHttpMessageCodecs(configurer: ServerCodecConfigurer) {
            configurer.customCodecs().register(JsonPatchHttpMessageConverter())
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the router and the handler:

```
@Configuration
class GreetingRouter {
    @Bean
    fun route(greetingHandler: GreetingHandler): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> {
        return RouterFunctions
                .route(RequestPredicates.POST("/hello")
                        .and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.valueOf("application/json-patch+json"))), HandlerFunction { request: ServerRequest? -> greetingHandler.hello(request!!) })
    }

}


@Component
class GreetingHandler {
    fun hello(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        return request.bodyToMono(JsonPatch::class.java)
                .flatMap { jsonPatch: JsonPatch ->
                    ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/json-patch+json"))
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue("Received: $jsonPatch"))
                }
    }
}
```

And finally you can invoke this endpoint with curl for example:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/hello \
  -H 'content-type: application/json-patch+json' \
  -d '[
   {
      "op":"replace",
      "path":"/email",
      "value":"email@email.com"
   }
]'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Hugo Alves for this code, but there is a memory leak here, you should release the buffer:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.AvoidCatchingThrowable")
public Mono<JsonPatch> readMono(ResolvableType elementType, ReactiveHttpInputMessage message, Map<String, Object> hints) {
    return DataBufferUtils.join(message.getBody(), this.maxInMemorySize).flatMap(buffer -> {
        try (var in = buffer.asInputStream(true)) {
            try (var reader = Json.createReader(in)) {
                return Mono.just(Json.createPatch(reader.readArray()));
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            log.error("Error reading Json Patch Http message", t);
            return Mono.error(new HttpMessageConversionException(t.getMessage(), t));
        }
    })
    .doOnDiscard(PooledDataBuffer.class, DataBufferUtils::release);
}
```